# Why there is difference in HashMap and Hastable method of put?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

I was wondering for `put` method difference in `HashMap` and `Hashtable`

`HashTable` put method code

```
Entry tab[] = table;
     int hash = key.hashCode();
     int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;
     for (Entry<K,V> e = tab[index] ; e != null ; e = e.next) {
         if ((e.hash == hash) && e.key.equals(key)) {
             V old = e.value;
             e.value = value;
             return old;
         }
     }
```

`HashMap` put method code

```
int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
     int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
     for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
         Object k;
         if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
             V oldValue = e.value;
             e.value = value;
             e.recordAccess(this);
             return oldValue;
         }
     }
```

why hashtable has different code for finding index?

```
int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;
```

while hashMap has `hash()` function provided by jdk designers.

Comment: that same things done by hash() function for hashmap

Comment: Both get the hash by a call to `hashCode`. The difference is a call to `indexFor` method. Do you know what this method does? Is it not just implementing the line in question?

Comment: Because there is. `Hashtable` was written around 1995, `HashMap` around 1997, not by entirely the same people. You would have to ask the authors to get anything but opinion.

Comment: but anyhow they providing updates so can't they modified class of hashtable ?

Comment: Certainly. Why exactly do you think they should do so?

Comment: HashMap made incompatible design decisions, used incompatible names, etc. It dropped automatic synchronization, for example. They couldn't just change Hashtable, or existing code would break, so they made new classes.

Comment: @user2357112 you're right about the incompatible pieces, but the motive was good, creating an unsynchronized version (which also allows null values) enabled developers that needed a single thread program hash-table - to execute their programs much faster!

Answer (score 0):

What is `0x7FFFFFFF` in binary? It's `01111111111111111111111111111111`.

Note that the leftmost *bit* is `0`. That means that the number is **always** positive (Since the leftmost *bit* is zero). Because of the `&`, every number that'll be `&`-ed with this binary will be *non-negative* since:

```
01111111111111111111111111111111
Anything                          &
--------------------------------
0 ← Always
```

After this, the `%` operator is used to ensure that we are in the range of `tab.length`.

You didn't post the implementation of how `HashMap` generates the index. I don't think it's very different. After all they have a very similar logic.

`HashMap` calls `indexFor` which is doing: `return h & (length-1);`

Important note: `HashTable` is older than `HashMap`, it's no wonder that there are difference implementations.

Answer (score 0):

HashTable:

```
int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;
```

which means:
hash - without the leftmost bit (sign) modulo the table length

HashMap:

```
int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
```

is calling:

```
static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
   return h & (length-1);
}
```

which means modulo length-1
not a big difference there, and actually `modulo length-1` means that the maximum value we can get is length-2. Here, the length-1 assures that we won't run into a scenario we'll get `0xFFFFFFFF` and actually the highest value we might get will be `0xFFFFFFFE`.

The difference is in the lower bits (in HashMap vs. Higher bits in HashTable). And now we should ask (recursively) why is that. And the answer is hiding in the hash() method which appears in the first row of the code (above) and which also differs from the HashTable implementation:

```
int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
```

and the explanation is found in the [*hash() method*](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/a42d6999734b/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java):

```
           /**
  258      * Applies a supplemental hash function to a given hashCode, which
  259      * defends against poor quality hash functions.  This is critical
  260      * because HashMap uses power-of-two length hash tables, that
  261      * otherwise encounter collisions for hashCodes that do not differ
  262      * in lower bits. Note: Null keys always map to hash 0, thus index 0.
  263      */
  264     static int hash(int h) {
  265         // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
  266         // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
  267         // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
  268         h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
  269         return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
  270     }
  271
```